# Example of ListView in google SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I have checked [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List7.html) on the google SDK and it doesnt work when I click on an item. I have change the listener to `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` and it works. Someone could tell me why?

Comment: I put an hyperlink to that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the listener to onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) and works ok.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the activity extends ListActivity. In your code, you might be extending Activity and inflating the listview in your layout file.

onListItemClick should be used when you inflate listview in your activity (when not extending ListActivity).

Comment: No i havent extend from Activity, I have copied the code just like in the example.